I generate with OpenModelica V.122.3 an FMU and run that in SIMULINK. The model runs on OpenModelica without Errors and in Simulink at Start error
SIMULINK FMU Import seams to work correctly ! I think there is something wrong in FMU-Generator in OpenModelica V.1.22.3.
Has someone similar problems with OpenModelica FMU-generator?
Support or HELPHELP Expirenceassasasasa

We need more info. What operating system do you have? What is the actual error you get? What version of Matlab?
